# Count elements from json using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to count no of element from json response. I would like to count number of id occurrence from below response :

```
{ "scores": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "100"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "77"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "96"
    }]}
```

Comment: As highlighted by @ILostMySpoon it is customary to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried multiple option like converting json to list and then use length function to retrieve length.Even i am trying to create python script but no luck so far because i am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the response in string and then use Split String like:

```
${response_list}  Split String  ${response}  id
${item_count}  Get Length  ${response_list}
${item_count}  Evaluate  ${item_count} - 1
```